# General term of a sequence_

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let $$a_1=-12,a_2=-6,a_3=-4,a_4=-3,....$$ be a sequence. What is   $a_n$?.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Presenting a sequence and looking for the rule is an ill-defined problem.  In some cases, if you present a lot of terms, you can heuristically say that this is some recognized sequence (for a marvelous collection, look at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences). The sequence you present could be $-\frac{12}{n}$ in which case the next number is $-2.4$.  It could be a list of negative divisors of 12; the next one of those is $-2$.  It could be a sequence with constant third difference (the next one is $0$).

Comment: $$a_n = -\left\lfloor \frac{12}{n} \right\rfloor + 22\left(1+\frac{n-\frac{9}{2}}{\left|n-\frac{9}{2}\right|}\right)$$ ;-)

Answer (score 4):

A possible series:

$$a_n = -\frac{12}{n}$$

$$a_1 = -\frac{12}{1} = -12$$

$$a_2 = -\frac{12}{2} = -6$$

et cetera...

Comment: I came up to $a_{n+1}=a_n\frac{n}{n+1}$, but with $a_1=-12$ it is equivalent to yours.

Comment: @Babak Well done! Maybe yours can be adapted to other series! Indeed it depends on $a_1$ :D So it's more general!

Answer (score 0):

you could look for a solution of the form

$a_n=b+cn+dn^2+en^3$

and solve the linear system

or use the finite difference method of polynomial interpolation.

you may find this

$a_n=-12+6(n-1)-2(n-1)(n-2)+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{2}$

Comment: Seems like a bit complicated. $4$ unknowns? One shall then need to solve a $4x4$ system, it doesn't seem the best way. Maybe it works, but not the best way..

Comment: The finite differences method is much faster.

Comment: Intuition is even faster :D